# Put each occurence of a select in a new column (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-view

I have an SQL database which contains a simple table made of 4 column. These columns are: "Name", "Time", "Day" and "Month". I have to show in a view how many time the Person "A" has did something at the "Time" B in the same day. Using a select, i would get each occurence as a new row, like

[image: this.]

But i would like to have something like

[image: this:]

Is that possible in SQL?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the maximum number of times per day, then use `group_concat()`:

```
select name, day, group_concat(time) as times
from t
group by name, day;
```

If you do, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name, day,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then time end) as time_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then time end) as time_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then time end) as time_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then time end) as time_4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, date order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name, day;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using mysql 5.x you can use a pivot table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Name` VARCHAR(1),
>   `Time` VARCHAR(5),
>   `Day` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Name`, `Time`, `Day`)
> VALUES
>   ('A', '11:00', '1/10'),
>   ('A', '12:00', '1/10'),
>   ('A', '13:00', '1/10'),
>   ('A', '17:00', '1/10'),
>     ('A', '10:00', '2/10'),
>   ('A', '12:00', '2/10'),
>   ('A', '14:00', '2/10'),
>   ('A', '17:00', '2/10');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `Name`, 
> IF(@date = `Day`,@rn:= @rn +1,@rn:= 1) rn
> ,`Time`
> ,@date := `Day` 'Day'
> FROM table1, (SELECT @rn:= 0,@date := '')a
> ORDER BY  `Name`,`Day`,`Time`
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | rn | Time  | Day 
> :--- | -: | :---- | :---
> A    |  1 | 11:00 | 1/10
> A    |  2 | 12:00 | 1/10
> A    |  3 | 13:00 | 1/10
> A    |  4 | 17:00 | 1/10
> A    |  1 | 10:00 | 2/10
> A    |  2 | 12:00 | 2/10
> A    |  3 | 14:00 | 2/10
> A    |  4 | 17:00 | 2/10
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.`rn` = "', `rn`,'", `Time`,"")) AS time_',rn)
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM (SELECT 
> `Name`, 
> IF(@date = `Day`,@rn:= @rn +1,@rn:= 1) rn
> ,`Time`
> ,@date := `Day` 'Day'
> FROM table1, (SELECT @rn:= 0,@date := '')a
> ORDER BY  `Name`,`Day`,`Time`) t1;
>
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `Name`,  ', @sql, ' ,`Day`
>                   FROM (SELECT 
> `Name`, 
> IF(@date = `Day`,@rn:= @rn +1,@rn:= 1) rn
> ,`Time`
> ,@date := `Day` "Day"
> FROM table1, (SELECT @rn:= 0,@date := "") a
> ORDER BY  `Name`,`Day`,`Time`)  s
>                  GROUP BY s.`Name`,s.`Day`
>                 ORDER BY s.`Name`,s.`Day`');
> #SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | time_1 | time_2 | time_3 | time_4 | Day 
> :--- | :----- | :----- | :----- | :----- | :---
> A    | 11:00  | 12:00  | 13:00  | 17:00  | 1/10
> A    | 10:00  | 12:00  | 14:00  | 17:00  | 2/10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cc304e745d2578aa8e9d8b6b74496481)*